# Extend existing Firefox extension/Use functionality of existing Firefox extension in own extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, dependencies

I am planning to start writing a Firefox extension in the near future and found out that part of the functionality I would like my extension to have is already done in another extension. Now I am wondering if it is possible to program an extension that uses the functionality of another extension (i.e. that the existing extension would have to be installed before mine). Is there for example the possibility to call another extensions functions? 
I am not trying to pass off somebody elses work as my own (hence the dependency on the existing extension), I just think it might not be necessary to program the same functionality twice.

I would assume that other people also had this problem/question, but unfortunately I could not find any answer on Stackoverflow or the internet in general. Apparently it is possible to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138462/how-do-i-modify-an-existing-firefox-extension) an existing extension, but this is not exactly what i want.

I'm happy for any tips or pointers!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no documentation about a reliable way to achieve this (there used to be a way in Firefox < 4) but you should be able to roll your own dependency check in your add-on code using the AddonManager API:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAllAddons(function(aAddons) {
  // Here aAddons is an array of Addon objects
});
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Add-on_Manager#Accessing_installed_add-ons

Additionally, if you distribute your add-on through the main add-ons site (https://addons.mozilla.org) you can list up to three add-ons that yours depends upon. That doesn't stop people from installing your add-on without its dependency but it should give a good user user experience to the vast majority of your addon's potential users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Luckyrat!
That seems like it should work. After thinking about the implications of your comment I looked a bit more into the topic and found out that it seems to be possible to call functions of other extensions as long as both extensions are overlay addons. I think with that information I should be able to get this to work!